# How can I bind an NFS/CIFS mountpoint on the host inside of a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker-compose file that describes a service.

The service will be monitoring a folder on the host, and doing something with any files that appear in that folder.

The folder on the host may be a local folder (in which case simple bind mounts work fine), but it might also be an NFS/CIFS mountpoint, where the files are coming from another server. This is proving to be more difficult.

If my `docker-compose.yml` file says this:

```
services:
    filesystem_watcher:
        ...
        volumes:
            - ./files:/files
```

If the `files` directory on the host is an NFS mountpoint, the docker container will NOT see those files in `/files`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Apparently there's a way to define an [NFS/CIFS connection as a volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-service-which-creates-an-nfs-volume). Unfortunately, that means I, as a developer, would need to know information about the NFS/CIFS server ahead of time. I may not have that information for the production environment. It would be nice if I could just define a folder on the host to bind into the container, and if the admins running the server in production decide to make that into a remote mountpoint of some kind, it will just work.

Comment: If you don't actually want your container isolated from the host filesystem, would running the program directly on the host make more sense?  I know once upon a time Docker wouldn't notice mount(8) calls that happened after the Docker daemon started; does restarting the Docker daemon help your setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze Just because I want to mount one host folder into the docker container doesn't mean I want to forgo every other advantage Docker provides. It appears that you are correct - if the remote server is mounted before the container starts up, the container will see it. If the remote server is mounted on the host after the container starts up, the container won't see it.